# Distorted created face

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces, svg

I’m fairly new to blender.Thanks in advance for any help.

Using blender 2.82

1.import Svg and convert all of its curves into meshes then join all meshes.

2.Scale and rotate object. Edit mode and select all of object and creat face. Extrude Object.

3.in Edit mode with face select; select a few connected faces with shift held And press “F” key to create face out of selected faces.
[image]

[image]

This is the problem I’m getting.

I’m trying to make a few faces one solid face without it distorting and what it seems to be doing here is breaking at a part in inverting out on the next side.

Comment: can you please rotate correctly the attached images?

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Also, please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.